# cannot install "code": classic confinement requires snaps under /snap or symlink from /snap to /var/lib/snapd/snap

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro, ln

how I can fix it? I've tried to create "soft link" like `sudo ln /snap /var/lib/snapd/snap` and also `sudo ln /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap` --> but it doesn't work. I just want to install VSCode in Manjaro

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap`
it worked for me I am using manjaro

Answer (score 182):

You must make a symbolic link to get it to work:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

That way worked for me.

Comment: Works perfectly with Manjaro distribution (installing Android Studio package)

Answer (score 5):

I use Manjaro too and have the same problem today, it happens after update some pkgs. And snapd can't install vscode for now.

A good alternative to "snapd" is "yay", for Manjaro. Simple install.

```
pamac install yay
```

```
yay package-name
```

If nothing works, you should uninstall the vscode first and delete the **.desktop** file located on **/home/your_username/.local/share/applications**, and use .deb front vscode website.

To install I downloaded the .deb version on Visual Studio Code website, and converted it to something pacman could install.

Now a little tutorial on how to do that

## How to install .deb on manjaro (arch linux)

The package that convert .deb is debtap, but it is only available on AUR.

Using **yay** u can install debtap

```
yay -S debtap
```

With debtap installed execute the command below to init debtap

```
sudo debtap -u
```

Now is possible to convert .deb

```
debtap your_package.deb
```

And finally use pacman to install the converted pkg

```
sudo pacman -U your-converted-pakage.pkg.tar.zst
```

Or u can try out this
[another tutorial](https://lobotuerto.com/blog/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-in-manjaro-linux/)